# Receiving Twilio messages from a random shortcode instead of my assigned number

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio, twilio-api

I'm using Twilio to send SMS messages. I have set my from field in the API call to use my Twilio assigned phone number. However, when I send a message, I receive it from a random shortcode, like 54235, instead of my assigned Twilio number.

I would like to receive messages from my Twilio assigned number and not from a random shortcode. Is there a setting in the Twilio console that I need to change to achieve this?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you try sending a text to a different carrier? For example, if you are using ATT try send to Verizon. Maybe your carrier is causing this to happen?

Comment: Is it possible that the country code from the sender is different than the country code of the receiving number?